# How to check memcached's capacity using php

Tags: php, memcached

Not sure how to determine memcached's capacity (how full it is) using php. Can't seem to find any documentation on it either... Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually kept looking around - the more useful info can come from:

```
<?php
    $memcache_obj = new Memcache;
    $memcache_obj->addServer('memcache_host', 11211);
    $memcache_obj->addServer('failed_host', 11211);

    $stats = $memcache_obj->getExtendedStats('slabs');
    print_r($stats);
?>
```

This actually outputs more relevant info based on the way memcached allocates memory.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`getStats`](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getstats.php):

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$stats = $m->getStats();
echo 'Capacity: ' . $stats['bytes'] . '/' . $stats['limit_maxbytes'] . ' Bytes';
```

Comment: Note that, under most normal circumstances, memcached will stay "near full" most of the time, as unused entries are naturally removed as the cache gets full. An empty memcached is a sad memcached.

Comment: @duskwuff Yup, but it may be useful to get the current capacity in a debugging context, where the cache is cleared before analysis.

Comment: In a debugging context, sure. Just don't assume that "full" means that you shouldn't try to put more data in!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - I actually went with `$memcache_obj->getExtendedStats('slabs');` which gives more detailed info on each of the slabs (which is how memcached allocates memory).

Comment: @duskwuff the proper term of unused is LRU least recently used